# Recently viewed pages in AEM

Tags: aem

I am trying to implement a feature where user can see what all last 5 pages he visited during current session. This is for anonymous user as site does not have any login/registration module available.

I can think of creating a data structure in user current session and add page names there and as user browse page from page, add page name in that collection using either request post processor or in a servlet. This servlet can be called using a HTL component passing json data to UI. Challenge here would be to maintain a consistent user session across journey.

OR

I can use some third party tool say Adobe analytics or Target etc for same?

Any suggestion?

Comment: Can't you use browser history object in client side scripting? AEM is mostly session less so using session is going to be problematic. Analytics data can be extracted but that will also be client side work using complex API.

Comment: as @i.net said, AEM should be mostly session-less. I would give it a try to the aem context hub. that allows you to easily store user information on its browser storage. You can then use JS to retrieve that and use it as you wish.